# Module Exponential problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Here is the problem:

$ 445^{445} + 225^{225} $ mod 7

So, I know how to calculate this $445^{445}$ and this $225^{225}$ separately. But i don't know how to add them and then mod 7.

In other words i can do  $445^{445}$ mod 7 and  $225^{225}$ mod 7, but I don't know how to add them first, than mod 7.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can do them separately, add them and then modulo 7 once more (if needed) for the final answer.

Comment: I just tried that, and it works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7 $

So  $445^{445} + 225^{225} \equiv (445 \mod 7)^{445 \mod 6} +(225 \mod 7)^{225 \mod 6} \equiv 4^1+(1)^3 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there:
$$x+y \mod n \equiv (x \mod n) + (y\mod n) \mod n$$